# Applescript or automator to print only 3 first pages of a pdf

Tags: macos, automator, pdf

I'd like to automate printing the first 3 pages of a PDF. It's fine if the document has to be split.

I have Adobe Acrobat Pro installed as well.

Comment: do you want them printed one-sided or two-sided?

Comment: From command line, you can use the lpr command with option -o page-ranges=1-3. For example file name aa,pdf  use lpr aa.pdf -o page-ranges=1-3

Comment: @StevenPeters yes, it should be printed recto-verso

Comment: Do you want to create a Finder service using key combinations? Something like this:
⌘+O [Open file]
delay 5 [Wait Acrobat to load]
⌘+P [Open print dialog]
Tab Tab Tab ... [goto pages field]
Keytroke "1,2,3"
etc?

Comment: @MateusRibeiro not really, but will do it like that if needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will prompt you to select the PDF file, then print the first 3 pages of it(change the `sourceFile` variable if you want to choose the PDF in another way):

```
set sourceFile to (choose file with prompt "Choose a PDF file:" of type {"PDF"})
do shell script "lpr " & quoted form of POSIX path of sourceFile & " -o page-ranges=1-3"
```

If you want to have a drag-and-drop application:

```
on open droppedItem set sourceFile to POSIX path of droppedItem
do shell script "lpr " & quoted form of POSIX path of sourceFile & " -o page-ranges=1-3" end open
```

Comment: This did the trick, I created an  app with
 `on open droppedItem
 
 set sourceFile to POSIX path of droppedItem
 do shell script "lpr " & quoted form of POSIX path of sourceFile & " -o page-ranges=1-3"
 
end open` . For some reason `-o sides=two-sided-long-edge` doesn't work. I made the default printer setiing double sided, so it works for now.